# Moving SwipeItem in CollectionView to change position

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, maui

I have a CollectionView which is bound to a List of elements. Within the CollectionView.ItemTemplate there is a DataTemplate x:DataType="..." to get to the Data. Below that, there is a SwipeView with a Label in a Frame and a corresponding SwipeItem for the Action.

Question: Is there a way that allows a user to move the Frames up/down to bring the displayed elements in the order in which he wants to see them? Let's call it a Drag&Drop of the Frames/Content that is presented to the user?

How can I achieve this?

==== **Additional information regarding comment** ====

Looking on the Screenshot, I thought I should add the DragOverCommand, DragLeaveCommand and DropCommand in a DropGestureRecognizer on the Frame. I added it like this, but only DragStartingCommand is fired:

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <DragGestureRecognizer CanDrag="True"
                           DragStartingCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DragStartingCommand}"
                           DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

    <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True"
                           DragLeaveCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DragLeaveCommand}"
                           DragLeaveCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                           DragOverCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DragOverCommand}"
                           DragOverCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                           DropCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DropCommand}"
                           DropCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

In addition, what I was trying to reach is that the dragged item "W" is moved from the very bottom (and visually excluded from there) while moving.

[image]

Then also the positions of the Frames have below the position they should be dropped have to move downwards to provide the space for the inserted element. I tried to show it in a screenshot changed in Paint

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use drag and drop gesture to change the position of item in CollectionView. So I made a demo. It's a little bit complicated and i will be very happy if you could go through my code and have a try.

First comes the MainPage,

```
<ContentPage
...
x:Name="this"
>

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                   IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                   IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <StackLayout >
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="60" Color="Blue" IsVisible="{Binding IsDraggedOver}"/>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White"
                          Padding="10" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large"
                            HeightRequest="50">
                        </Label>
                         <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <DragGestureRecognizer
                                        CanDrag="True"                                    
                                        DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragStartingCommand ,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                        DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                         </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Frame>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <DropGestureRecognizer
                                AllowDrop="True"
                                DragLeaveCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragLeaveCommand ,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                DragLeaveCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                DragOverCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragOverCommand ,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                DragOverCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                DropCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DropCommand ,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                DropCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

For MainPageViewModel.cs, we define the drag and drop command.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCollection { get; set; }
    = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public Item DraggedItem; // this proeprty track the item being dragged

    public Command DragLeaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {
                 ItemCollection.Remove(DraggedItem);
            });
        }
    }

    public Command DragOverCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {
                foreach (var item in ItemCollection)
                {
                    if (e == item && item != DraggedItem)
                    {
                        item.IsDraggedOver = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.IsDraggedOver = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // when user drop the item, we do two things: 1. delete the dragged item and insert the dragged item before the item which is dragged over (targetItem)
    public Command DropCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>(async (e) =>
            {
                var draggedItem = DraggedItem;

                var targetItem = e;

                if (draggedItem == null || targetItem == null || draggedItem == targetItem)
                    return;

                ItemCollection.Remove(draggedItem);
                var insertIndex = ItemCollection.IndexOf(targetItem);
                ItemCollection.Insert(insertIndex, draggedItem);
                foreach (var item in ItemCollection)
                {
                    item.IsDraggedOver = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public Command DragStartingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {
                DraggedItem = e;
            });
        }
    }

    public Command FavoriteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {

            });
        }
    }

    public Command DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {
                ItemCollection.Remove(e);
            });
        }
    }

    //add some test item
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ItemCollection.Add(new Item
        {
            Title = "first item"
        });
        .....
        ItemCollection.Add(new Item
        {
            Title = "second item"
        });

        ItemCollection.Add(new Item
        {
            Title = "Eighth item"
        });
    }
}
```

Item in ItemCollection:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }



    private bool isDraggedOver;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsDraggedOver
    {
        get
        {
            return isDraggedOver;
        }
        set
        {
            isDraggedOver = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsDraggedOver)));
        }
    }

    public Item()
    {
    }
}
```

Actually I just made a small demo and there should be some details you may improvements UI for your project.

Anyway thanks for your reading. Hope it works for you!

Comment: I will test it by the mid of this week and let you know. There are  a couple of things that I‘ve seen in your solution that might have prevented it from working when I tried it: there was CanDrag and AllowDrop switched to True which I didn’t. The other thing is, I have to change the Order in the List, so that the bound Items are really switched? So, does it mean I have to do this, otherwise it won’t work? Just a graphical solution is not possible? I think, what I also need to do graphically is to show the user that the items before and after place to drop move while dragging

Comment: The default values of CanDrag and AllowDrop are true. (if set them to false, how can we implement drag and drop gesture?) I just set it explicitly. And yes , the order of ObservableCollection which ItemSource binds to has been changed. Otherwise the UI won't change. That's what data binding does.

Comment: ```what I also need to do graphically is to show the user that the items before and after place to drop move while dragging``` This is a good idea to improve user experience. I will have a try.

Comment: * The default values of CanDrag and AllowDrop are true. (if set them to false, how can we implement drag and drop gesture?)* - I was wondering why no Drag&Drop-Action was shown when I tried this gesture, so when you used it explicitly, I thought this was mandatory for this UI-Element  Currently, I can’t test it, but will let you know more, when I tried with your solution. But, so far from reading over it, it all makes sense and from a Binding perspective also. I was only a bit in a conflict, since I used a filter on a different list with all elements having a IsSelected value True to show

Comment: I think it won't  have much effect  if using a filter. Because drag and drop in this case only change the position of the collection. It won't change any other property of the element. It would be better if you could post relevant code.

Comment: I make some changes. I add a boxview which HeightRequest=2 to indicate the insert position. When drag over the item, the boxview will show. I bind the Boxview IsVisible property to IsDraggedOver property of Item.

Comment: I tried your code and what I can see now is the Frame dragged, but just when I the Frame is tapped for longer. Is there a way to shorten the tap-time to drag it earlier?

I added additional information to my question. Only the DragStartingCommand is fired, even when I added the DropGestureRecognizer with the same Binding command as for the DragStartingCommand and added it to the Frame itself.

Additionally, I wanted to "move" the Frame, so that "W" is moved and not visible as in Screenshot 1. Then the position of the Frames below the insert position should move downwards as in Screenshot 2

Comment: If you drag the frame, then for DropGestureRecognizer should attach to the parent of the frame, just like my code put it in a stacklayout.

Comment: I think we couldn't shorten the tap-time because we have to tell the difference between drag and tap gesture. I made some changes : 1. when drag leave , remove the draggeditem so it would be excluded; 2. change the heightrequest of boxview

Comment: I marked it as answer - thanks for all the communication and good solutions 